# need help Understanding javascript gallery code

Tags: javascript, slideshow

1. Hi I have created a slideshow for my html with the function to show a gallery of pictures one at a time with a function to showcase the next picture by clicking the arrow to move to the next picture, I am still unclear of this line of code and how it relates to the function of the slideshow. I referred to this website to complete the slide show : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp
   May I ask if someone could explain what this line of code does ? Thanks a bunch !

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

//calling of functions to let the slide move to the next picture
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if ( n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display= "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: Which line is it that you are querying?

Comment: @Tom Mettam Preferably the entire code but mainly focusing on the function showSlides(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of what this code does:

`var slideIndex = 1;`

Initialise the variable `slideIndex` to `1`

`showSlides(slideIndex);`

Show the first slide (see comments below for why `1` is the first slide and not 0)

```
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
```

This function will skip ahead `n` slides and show that slide. Note that this function is never actually called in the code that you have posted.

```
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
```

This sets `slideIndex` to `n` and then shows the `n`th slide. Note that this function is also never actually called in the code that you have posted.

```
function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
```

Inside the `showSlides` function, we declare an empty variable `i`.

Then we look in the DOM (the HTML) for elements, some with a `class` of `mySlides` and some with a class of `dot`. Note that these functions can return multiple elements (or none).

```
    if ( n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
```

If we've reached the end of the list (gone past the last slide) we set the slideIndex back to 1.

```
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
```

If we've gone back past the first slide, go back to the end

```
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

Sets the `display` style of all slides to `none`. This removes all of the slides from the `dom` (effectively hides them)

```
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
```

I'm not exactly sure what a "dot" is in this context, without seeing the html, it might be an indicator of what slide you're on.

This code removes the "active" class from all of the elements with "dot" in their class. Note that this isn't a good way to remove a class - (what if there is another class called 'activePanel' or something?)

```
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display= "block";
```

This sets the `display` style of the slide of index `slideIndex - 1` to `block`, effectively making it visible (it was previously set to 'none' which hides it)

It's `slideIndex - 1` because the logic above starts the index from 1 for some reason, whereas the array is zero-indexed. No reason to do this really.

```
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
```

This adds the `active` class to the `dot` of index `slideIndex-1`.

A few extra comments:

A `class` is a css class. It basically adds a style to the element.

Comment: Still not understanding the logic behind slides[slideIndex-1].style.display= "block";
Shouldn't it just be slides[slideIndex].style.display= "block"; to set the current slide visible? @Tom Mettam

Comment: Because the guard `if (n < 1)` means that the index can never be zero. Array indexes start at zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
// set the index of the picture in the slideshow to 1
var slideIndex = 1;

// Calls the main function 'showSlides', and passes in the 1 
// from above
showSlides(slideIndex);

//calling of functions to let the slide move to the next picture
// This function probably gets called when user clicks the next
// button. It adds n to the index, and calls the main function 'showSlides' again.
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}


function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

// Main function, takes a number argument for the slide number
// to show, and assigns this number to the variable 'n'
function showSlides(n) {
//  This variable is for iterating (adding)
    var i;

// This variable selects the mySlides element from the DOM HTML
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

// This variable selects the dot element from the DOM HTML
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

// If the number passed into the main function is greater_than 
// the number of slides, then set the variable slideIndex to 1.
    if ( n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}

// If the number passed into the main function is less_than 
// the number of slides, then set the variable slideIndex to the number of slides.
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}

// Iterate through all of the slides, and do what's in the {} 
// to each slide. Set the display style to none to hide them.
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

// Iterate through all of the dots, and do what's in the {} 
// to each dot element. Remove the class name 'active' for CSS.
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

// Set the display style of the slide before (-1) to 'block'
// This makes it visible
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display= "block";

// Set the class name of the dot before (-1) to 'active'
// This is probably styled in the CSS
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: `It adds 1 to the index` is incorrect, the function adds `n` to the index

Comment: From the example, when called it adds 1 or subtracts 1.

<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

Comment: Doesn't matter, that's usage and not implementation

Comment: That's why I updated it and thanked you dude. I added the comment so that a beginner like myself could understand it :)

Comment: @joseph.harding Still not understanding the logic behind slides[slideIndex-1].style.display= "block";
Shouldn't it just be slides[slideIndex].style.display= "block"; to set the current slide visible?

Answer (score 0):

**slideIndex** holds the initial index of your slide show i.e the visible image.

**`showslides(n)`** is a function which accepts a **parameter** and the parameter must be a number which is the index of the picture to show.
How this function works is that it loops through the given gallery and show the image with the index passed to the function, and hides other images.

**`currentSlide(n)`** works with the **`showSlides(n)`** function, this way any value passed to **`currentSlide(n)`** will be the current image to show. This way way you click on a thumbnail for example that particular image will be visible while others are hidden, because the image index was passed as the argument to **`currentSlide(n)`**

**`plusSlides(n)`** this will just add the value of `n` to `slideIndex` at most case it would be just **`1`** so if `slideIndex` was **3** calling on `plusSlides(n)` will look for the forth index. - same implies for `minusSlides(n)` they can be called alias for **next** and **prev**